# Using apply to quickly fill in a column of a pandas dataframe using a specific function?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following pandas dataframe as an input:

`df= pd.DataFrame({"C": [2,4,7,17,39], "D": [0,0,0,0,0]})`

Output:

    `C   D
0   2   0
1   4   0
2   7   0
3   17  0
4   39  0`

I want to apply a function to column D such that it takes the current C value and subtracts the previous C value and adds this to the previous D value. The first element in D is necessarily 0.

Ex. For the fourth row, the column D value will be 39 - 17 + 15 = **37**

The desired output would be as shown below:

`C   D
0   2   0
1   4   2
2   7   5
3  17  15
4  39  37`

I can get the desired result using a for loop that goes through every row and performs the calculation. My actual dataframe is several thousand lines and the calculation pulls on several columns. I was wondering if there was a more efficient, simpler routine that I could employ either using apply or shift or something similar but **not** a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `cumsum` on the *difference (current - previous)* of column C:

```
df['D'] = df['C'].diff().fillna(0).cumsum()
df

#    C     D
#0   2   0.0
#1   4   2.0
#2   7   5.0
#3  17  15.0
#4  39  37.0
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!